# How can I access window buttons on maximised windows?

Tags: window-buttons, maximized, 23.10

I've just upgradeed to Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic Minotaur. I'm realising a nice new feature, where any maximised window's top bar integrates with Ubuntu's status bar - it completely disappears. While I like this feature, I'm also noticing the Close, Maximise/Restore & Minimise buttons disappear from a window if it's maximised.

How can I access and use the window buttons on a maximised window?

EDIT: As advised by @Octopus, I'm attaching a screenshot:

[image]

Also, to answer his question, do I use any GNOME extensions, I do not. The same behaviour exists even when I completely disable GNOME extensions.

Comment: Upload a picture of how it looks.
Also, do you use any GNOME extensions, because I have 23.10, and don't have this.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Octopus. I've added the info you requested to my question.